# Use generics to specify type of return value

Tags: typescript, generics, google-chrome-extension, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I have this method on an Angular service:

```
 getFromSyncStorage(key: string): Promise<Object | LastErrorType> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (v: Object) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        resolve(v && v[key]);
      });
    });
  }
```

note that `LastErrorType` is

```
export type LastErrorType = typeof chrome.runtime.lastError;
```

here is the problem, sometimes I pass a key, and I know the "return" type will be an array, for example:

```
getAllRunHistory() {
    return this.cds.getFromSyncStorage('my-special-key');
}
```

but if I do this:

```
getAllRunHistory() : Promise<Array<any>>{
    return this.cds.getFromSyncStorage('my-special-key');
}
```

tsc will complain and say that the return type is not assignable to `Promise<Array<any>>`.

how can I use generics, so that this general-purpose `getFromSyncStorage` method can be typed properly?

Comment: What if you list all the possible types in getFromSyncStorage declaration? That is, Array<any>, Number, String, etc.

Comment: Uhhh idk, I could do that, but then it would become meaningless right? given what you're suggesting, I might as well just use `Promise<any>`, but I think there is a better way, just not sure how to do it...I believe the answer is generics.

Comment: Well, I should have said to list all the types you actually store in chrome.storage.

Comment: Which would probably be almost any type right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with generics.  Create a type representing the mapping from key to value type.  In your case, it's something like:

```
type SyncStorageMap = {
    "my-special-key": Array<any>,
    [k: string]: Object // everything else
}
```

Then, type your method like this:

```
getFromSyncStorage<K extends keyof SyncStorageMap>(
  key: K
): Promise<SyncStorageMap[K] | LastErrorType> {
   // impl
}
```

Note that you might have to use type assertions in the implementation of that method if the compiler can't verify that `"my-special-key"` corresponds to `Array<any>`.

Then this code:

```
getAllRunHistory() {
    return this.cds.getFromSyncStorage('my-special-key');
}
```

will be known to return `Promise<Array<any> | LastErrorType>`.  That's probably what you want unless you're sure that you will not get a `LastErrorType`, in which case you can do something like this instead:

```
type SyncStorageMap = {
    "my-special-key": Array<any>, // no error
    [k: string]: Object | LastErrorType // maybe error
}

getFromSyncStorage<K extends keyof SyncStorageMap>(
  key: K
): Promise<SyncStorageMap[K]> {
   // impl
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I think you overcomplicated this, I am about to add an answer

Comment: maybe you're right that if you need to specify the error type as well, then this is a better solution, hard to say

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22162

Answer (score 0):

Looks like generics is the right thing to use. We change the original method to this:

```
 getFromSyncStorage<T>(key: string): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (v) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        }
        resolve(v && v[key]);
      });
    });
  }
```

then we use it like so:

```
this.getFromLocalStorage<Array<MyType>>(mds.key).then(...)
```

one caveat though, I don't really know how to specify the error type for the promise, which sucks, but I think it's a deficiency with the Promise TypeScript typings :(

Comment: This answer allows the caller to specify the desired return type, but doesn't actually prevent the caller from specifying it incorrectly.  Nothing stops someone from saying `this.getFromLocalStorage<string>("my-special-key")` instead of `this.getFromLocalStorage<Array<MyType>>("my-special-key")`.  If you're okay with that, great.  But I imagined you wanted some type safety.